# CakePHP displaying checkbox options and corresponding values from database

Tags: php, cakephp

**Background**

I have a 'doctors' and a 'hospitals' table. They are linked(many to many) by a 'doctor_hospital' table.

**Problem**

While adding a doctor I want multiple check-boxes for selecting hospitals. The problem is I can't display hospitals 'name' as options and corresponding 'id' as values from the database.

**What I have tried**

The best I can do(and not get any error) is this:
[image]

**Code**

controller.php

```
$hospitals = $this->Hcp->Hospitals->find('all', ['fields' => ['id', 'name']]);
```

add.ctp

```
<?php
   foreach ($hospitals as $hospital) {
   echo $this->Form->control('hospitals', ['type' => 'select',
                                           'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                            $hospital->id => $hospital->name
                                          ]); 
            }
      ?>
```

**What I want**

when selecting the boxes, display 'name' but submit the corresponding 'id' back to the controller.

Comment: Try using value attribute for checkbox ....like 'value'=>$hospital->id

Comment: Didn't work. It throws an error saying "invalid argument for foreach loop"  (something like that)

Answer (score 0):

First, open your HospitalsTable.php and check if your `displayField` is set to "name" property (if you baked your model it should be).

Next, in your controller, use "list" finder:

```
$hospitals = $this->Hcp->Hospitals->find("list");
$this->set(compact("hospitals"));
```

And finally, in your template file:

```
echo $this->Form->control("hospitals._ids", ["type" => "select", "multiple" => "checkbox"]);
```

It should generate what you want.

More info: [CakePHP 3.x Forms](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html)

Comment: Didn't work. Still showing the same thing. Displayfield is 'name'.

Comment: It is correct way, and it should produce desired result. I suggest you to check bare bones example, which can be found in tutorial: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'form->checkbox' instead 'form->control'

```
<?php
       foreach ($hospitals as $hospital) {
          echo "<label>";
          echo $this->Form->checkbox('hospitals', ['value'=>$hospital->id]); 
          echo $hospital->name. "</label>";
       }
?>
```